# Testing code for the GMAIL application on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, debugging, gmail, responsive-design

I'm attempting to build a responsive email template and I'm having rendering issues when viewing the email on the GMAIL application for the iPhone. I was wondering if any fellow developers have any suggestions for testing and debugging code similar to how you would with Firebug/Developer Tools on a desktop.

I've been researching for some time now and only seem to find websites built to test the code in mobile browsers.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and hopefully something that Google will tackle soon. Their smartphone app does not honour media queries and basically renders emails as per the desktop viewport